# I need help showing and hiding data based on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Alright so I have a form. In the form I have a lot of check boxes. If a person clicks on the checkbox. It shows the field below the box. If they click on the checkbox again it makes the field below the checkbox disappear and makes the field have no value.

here is the code. I have JS running the show and hide. and Html calling it.

```
function ShowCutSewDescription() {
    var select = $('#send_item_to_cutsew');
    console.log(select)
    //select = parseInt(select);
    if (select.attr('checked', true)) {
        $('#cutsew-checked').show();
    }else {
        $('#cutsew-checked').hide();
    }
}

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sending item to Cut/Sew Manager</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="checkbox" name="send_item_to_cutsew" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" placeholder="Enter text" onchange="ShowCutSewDescription()">
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#cutsew-checked')` element with this Id is not in your question. Please add that

Comment: What problem do you actually face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes made**

> ► `select.attr('checked', true)` **to** `select.is(":checked")`
>
> ► `$('#send_item_to_cutsew')` **to** `$('[name="send_item_to_cutsew"]')` since there is no element with that Id.

**Working Demo**

```js
function ShowCutSewDescription() {
  var select = $('[name="send_item_to_cutsew"]');
  if (select.is(":checked")) {
    $('#cutsew-checked').show();
  } else {
    $('#cutsew-checked').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sending item to Cut/Sew Manager</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="checkbox" name="send_item_to_cutsew" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" placeholder="Enter text" onchange="ShowCutSewDescription()">
  </div>
  <div id="cutsew-checked">
    Sample box
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is using jQuery. If so, the selector that you have input is looking for something with an id of `send_item_to_cutsew`.

jQuery uses css selectors as a base, as referenced by this page: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

The proper way to get the input that you want based on the name is as follows:

```
var select = $('[name="send_item_to_cutsew]');
```

or you can set the id to the above like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="send_item_to_cutsew" name="send_item_to_cutsew" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" placeholder="Enter text" onchange="ShowCutSewDescription()">
```